# Multiple Quotes in String

Tags: python, string

In Python how would I write the string `'"['BOS']"'`.

I tried entering `"\"['BOS']\""` but this gives the output `'"[\'BOS\']"'` with added backslashes in front of the `'`.

Comment: you are looking at the `repr` of a string.  The data is what you are expecting.  Try printing the string and see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use triple quotes:

```
'''"['BOS']"'''
```

What you did (`"\"['BOS']\""`) is fine too.  You get the backslashes on output, but they aren't part of the string:

```
>>> a = "\"['BOS']\""
>>> a
'"[\'BOS\']"'    # this is the representation of the string
>>> print a
"['BOS']"    # this is the actual content
```

When you type an expression such as `a` into the console, it's the same as writing `print repr(a)`.  `repr(a)` returns a string that can be used to reconstruct the original value, hence the quotes around the string and the backslashes.

Comment: What if I want the literal string "''''''"

Comment: Cruncher:  You would use `'"\'\'\'\'\'\'"'`

Answer (score 4):

You should use triple quotes so that you don't need to use backslashes.

```
'''"['BOS']"'''
```

The reason you got `\`s in your output is because the python console adds them:

```
>>> s = '''"['BOS']"'''
>>> s
'"[\'BOS\']"'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the entire string with `"""` or `'''` (you would use `'''` if the outermost quotation marks were `"`) in cases like these to make things simpler.

`"""'"['BOS']"'"""`

Comment: This is a syntax error and the reason triple-quotes aren't always a complete solution. The end of this line is parsed as `'''`, which ends the string, followed by the fourth `'`.

Comment: @quornian Sorry, I reversed what I meant to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can build it dynamically as well:

```
>>> print('"{}"'.format("'[BOS]'"))
"'[BOS]'"
>>> print('"'+"'[BOS]'"+'"')
"'[BOS]'"
```