# How to pass a paragraph having multiple ( " ) and ( ' ) from a variable inside a string in django?

Tags: django, string, syntax

I want to pass a variable having a paragraph in which there are multiple uses of ( " ) and ( ' ). I am passing this variable inside another string which is an sql query in a django project.

For example -

variable1 = input()

command = "insert into table 1 values{"{}"}".format(variable1);

So in avbove code iif the user is entering some data with no ( " ) or ( ' ) it is working fine but when there is presence of these it just throws error.

Ho can I get independent of these symbols inside my input data and pass it as a query ?

I tried using raw input but when it comes to fetching data from a database and then passing that data containig multiple symbols of ( " ) and ( ' ) it just throws erre.

What I want is that it just ignore all these symbols present in my variable .

Comment: 1) You are potentially opening up yourself to SQL injection attacks. 2) If you use Django's built-in ORM you shouldn't need to generate SQL.

Comment: As well as triple-quoted strings, you can escape a quote `"\""`. Seconded about SQL injection ... NEVER do this. Django provides the means to execute raw SQL safely if you follow the guidelines: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql (there are edge cases where the ORM is just too cumbersome)

Comment: XKCD on SQL injection:  little Bobby Tables https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer:

[Multiple Quotes in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645394/multiple-quotes-in-string)

Try using

```
command = '''insert into table 1 values{"{}"}'''
command.format(variable1)
```